# How to code highlighted opening hours?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hour

This is a code that I forked over from [another codepen code](http://codepen.io/bengoddard/pen/boeEy) and modified to show only Monday - Friday, Saturday, and Sunday. However, I couldn't figured out how to modify the Javascript code to adapt to the new code that I edited. Help?

You can check out the modified codepen code that I created. http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/eJjdoE

HTML

```
<section class="openinghours">
    <div class="openinghourscontent section">

        <table class="opening-hours-table">
            <tr id="Monday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Monday at 9am to 6pm">
                <td>Monday-Friday</td>
                <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td class="closes">18:00</td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="Saturday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Saturday at 10am to 6pm">
                <td>Saturday</td>
                <td class="opens">10:00</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td class="closes">18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Sunday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Sunday at 11am to 4pm">
                <td>Sunday</td>
                <td class="opens">11:00</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td class="closes">16:00</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</section>
```

Javascript

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var weekday = [];
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var currentDay = weekday[currentDate.getDay()];

var currentTimeHours = currentDate.getHours();
currentTimeHours = currentTimeHours < 10 ? "0" + currentTimeHours : currentTimeHours;
var currentTimeMinutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
var timeNow = currentTimeHours + "" + currentTimeMinutes;

var currentDayID = "#" + currentDay; //gets todays weekday and turns it into id
$(currentDayID).toggleClass("today"); //this works at hightlighting today

var openTimeSplit = $(currentDayID).children('.opens').text().split(":");

var openTimeHours = openTimeSplit[0];
openTimeHours = openTimeHours < 10 ? "0" + openTimeHours : openTimeHours;

var openTimeMinutes = openTimeSplit[1];
var openTimex = openTimeSplit[0] + openTimeSplit[1];

var closeTimeSplit = $(currentDayID).children('.closes').text().split(":");

var closeTimeHours = closeTimeSplit[0];
closeTimeHours = closeTimeHours < 10 ? "0" + closeTimeHours : closeTimeHours;

var closeTimeMinutes = closeTimeSplit[1];
var closeTimex = closeTimeSplit[0] + closeTimeSplit[1];
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to accomplish. You have forked code that highlights hours and you want to change it. What are you trying to change it to? (input, desired output).

Comment: For example, if it's Tuesday, the "Monday-Friday" section isn't highlighted because the id is "Monday", I've been trying to figure out how to edit it so that "Monday-Friday" is highlighted for M, T, W, T, and Friday.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code to highlight if it is currently a weekday.
You have removed some of the functionality from the original codepen such as displaying if they are currently open so I have not updated the corresponding code for that.

I changed the ID of row "Monday" to "Weekday".

**JS:**

```
if (currentDate.getDay() != 0 && currentDate.getDay() != 6) { // if not Sunday or Sunday it must be a weekday
    $("#Weekday").toggleClass("today");
} else {
    $(currentDayID).toggleClass("today"); //this works at hightlighting today
}
```

Updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeBPYe)

**-- EDIT --**

Upon looking at it again I found this clearer.

```
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
  case 0:
    $("#Sunday").toggleClass("today");
    break;
  case 6:
    $("#Saturday").toggleClass("today");
    break;
  default:
    $("#Weekday").toggleClass("today");
    break;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhfj0b64/)

Comment: Your didn't work. I checked by adding var currentDay = weekday[0] (Sunday); and the "Sunday" hours didn't get highlighted.

Comment: The if statement I wrote checks `currentDate.getDay()`  not `currentDay` which is why it didn't update when you changed `currentDay`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jaydo who gave me helpful tip, I was able to re-edit my code and it works.

Here's the [code http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/eJjdoE](http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/eJjdoE)

HTML

```
<section class="openinghours">
    <div class="openinghourscontent section">

        <table class="opening-hours-table">
            <tr id="Weekday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Monday-Friday at 8am to 9pm">
                <td>Monday-Friday</td>
                <td class="opens">8:00am</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td class="closes">9:00pm</td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="Saturday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Saturday at 8am to 5pm">
                <td>Saturday</td>
                <td class="opens">8:00am</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td class="closes">5:00pm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Sunday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Sunday at 9am to 6pm">
                <td>Sunday</td>
                <td class="opens">9:00am</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td class="closes">6:00pm</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</section>
```

In which I changed "Monday" to "Weekday"

and in Javascript, I edited the weekday

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var weekday = [];
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Weekday";
weekday[2] = "Weekday";
weekday[3] = "Weekday";
weekday[4] = "Weekday";
weekday[5] = "Weekday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";
```

So that no matter which number I entered in, for example, `var currentDay = weekday[6];`, I get highlighted day.